# Running multiple queues on different connections in Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-8

I have case where i have regular jobs run via a default database queue, so the configuration looks like

```
conf/queue.php:
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

.env:
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Now, everything works fine, however, I need to add one specific case for a queue that needs to be run on sync (converting user submitted media that need to be present instantly)

I have tried configuring a new queue named **medialibrry** in `conf/queue.php` like this:

```
    'medialibrary' => 'sync',
```

And fire the necessary jobs in a queue named *medialibrary*. However, the only thing Laravel does is still use database connection and just inserts new rows that have *queue* column set to *medialibrary* instead of actually using "sync" like i've defined in `conf/queue.php`.

How do i use different queue drivers for different queues?

**edit**: thank you @kjones for the reply, i see it is done via `->onConnection('method')`. However, if anyone has had a problem with Spatie's Medialibrary needing to be synced specifically, i have found that there is a [->nonQueued()](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/api/defining-conversions#nonqueued) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onConnection()` method as follows (using the podcast example from the [Laravel queues documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues)):

```php
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->onConnection('sync');
```

Comment: oh damn i have missed that, thank you

Comment: np, to be fair they really should put it in the docs

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing queue name and queue driver. Your `queue.php` config must look like:

```
 'connections' => [
        // other connections
        'medialibrary' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],
  ]
```

And than you can dispatch jobs in sync:

```
ProcessMedia::dispatch($media)->onQueue('medialibrary');
```

Comment: i have configured the connection exactly as you wrote and fired an event exactly like you wrote like `->onQueue('medialibrary')` but it only adds a new job into the database with the queue name `medialibrary` on my default database driver instead of using sync